# ORACLE SQL find row with max date for each grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, analytic-functions

I am trying to write a query which will return only the rows, which time has the greatest value for each id

```
Table: positions
id          time       otherCols...
---------- ----------- ----------
1           1     
1           2      
3           1      
1           3      
2           1       
3           2
```

Result should look like:

```
id          time       otherCols...
---------- ----------- ----------      
1           3      
2           1       
3           2
```

I tried grouping by id but I don't know how to sort after that and pick only the top result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

An alternative method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

This is different from the first query in two respects:

- If there are duplicate times for an `id`, then this returns *all* rows for an `id`.  You can get that behavior using `rank()` in the first query.
- This will not return `NULL` `id` values or `id`s where the `time` is uniformly `NULL`.  The first query does.

Comment: Thanks for the queries, looks like second is much faster but they give different number of results.

Comment: @boneash . . . That would suggest that you have duplicate times for a given `id`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..) OVER (PARTITION BY ..)` analytic function without need of any subquery :

```
SELECT MAX(time) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY time) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS time_max,
       p.*
  FROM positions p
 ORDER BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dd8eb141ed5e7d88f5aeb49d43a2100b)</kbd>

Comment: Why not just use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: The OP wants an indeterminate number of extra columns.  For one or two, I would suggest `keep`, but for a general query there are other methods that are much less cumbersome to write.

Comment: Yes, I want just to filter out, columns should stay the same.

Comment: OK @boneash I understand now, then just need to add the other columns along with this analytic function.